Loading multiple certificates with titanium web proxy
I want titanium web proxy to load multiple certificates (.crt files to be exact) and use them to decrypt HTTPS traffic for servers associated with them. This is the code I currently use which allows for use of titanium web proxy certificate.
proxyServer.SupportedSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
proxyServer.CertificateManager.CertificateValidDays = 825;
proxyServer.CertificateManager.RootCertificateName = "TesterApp";
proxyServer.CertificateManager.RootCertificate = proxyServer.CertificateManager.LoadRootCertificate();
proxyServer.CertificateManager.CreateRootCertificate();
proxyServer.CertificateManager.TrustRootCertificate(machine);

It works fine. I think I can also choose one certificate and assign it to RootCertificate. Though, I am not sure how to assign multiple ones. I saw the feature of adding multiple certificates on HTTP Toolkit and I want to add the same functionality to my solution using titanium web proxy. I have checked the repo of titanium web proxy on github including issues and also the answers in SO, but I could not find anything helpful. I have used ChatGPT AI, which recommended non-existent methods and was not helpful in this case.
